# optimizing 3 variables in a differential equation based on available data point from solution of differential equation

Tags: python, optimization, gradient-descent, odeint

I have following data points (I call them actual data points):

```
y_data = np.array([0, 32.1463583, 33.1915926, 37.9100309, 39.2501778, 40.8225707, 48])
t_data = np.array([0, 26.75, 72.25, 163.4166667, 209.25, 525, 1250])
```

and I have a differential equation which is includes  y and t:

```
dy/dt=(1-y)/((a+b*t)*exp(-E/3060.8))
```

my goal is to optimize **a, b , and E** such that the solution of the above differential equation best fit my actual data (y_data).
to do this. I had the following steps in my mind:

```
1- set initial guess for a=1, b=20, E=10000 
2- create a for loop ( for 1000 iterations) 
3- solve differential equation using ODEint with initial guess 
4- Find difference between calculated value of y from solution of differential equation  at time equal to "t" with actual "y" value 
5- print error
6- update a to a , b, E and repeat from step 3
```

and here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Given data
y_data = np.array([0, 32.1463583, 33.1915926, 37.9100309, 39.2501778, 40.8225707, 48])
t_data = np.array([0, 26.75, 72.25, 163.4166667, 209.25, 525, 1250])

# Initial guess for parameters
a = 1
b = 20
E = 10000

# Number of iterations
iterations = 1000

# Tolerance for convergence
tolerance = 1e-6

# Step size for numerical gradient approximation
h = 1e-6

# Perform optimization
for i in range(iterations):
    # Calculate gradients using numerical gradient approximation
    def calculate_error(a, b, E):
        def model(y, t):
            return (1 - y) / ((a + b * t) * np.exp(-E / 3060.8))
        
        y_solution = odeint(model, y_data[0], t_data)
        error = np.mean(np.abs(y_solution[:, 0] - y_data))
        return error
    print (error)

    grad_a = (calculate_error(a + h, b, E) - calculate_error(a, b, E)) / h
    grad_b = (calculate_error(a, b + h, E) - calculate_error(a, b, E)) / h
    grad_E = (calculate_error(a, b, E + h) - calculate_error(a, b, E)) / h

    # Update parameters
    a -= 0.1 * grad_a
    b -= 0.1 * grad_b
    E -= 0.1 * grad_E

    # Check for convergence
    if abs(grad_a) < tolerance and abs(grad_b) < tolerance and abs(grad_E) < tolerance:
        break

# Output the optimized parameters
print("Optimized Parameters (a, b, E):", a, b, E)
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work and keep giving me constant error of "32.223947830786685". This is somehow indicating to me that the update function to update a, b and E doesn't work properly.
For reference, I used a function in this for

```
(calculate_error(a + h, b, E) - calculate_error(a, b, E))
```

to manually calculate the gradient of a, b , E.

Any suggestion as how to fix my issue? or any alternative solution to find bets a, b , E parameters?

Comment: You could solve that ODE perfectly easily by separation of variables. Why do you need to call odeint? Also, there will be only two independent parameters, not three. Are you sure that you have the correct differential equation - for instance, did you mean to have Et inside exp(), rather than just E?

Comment: @lastchance thanks for your response. I can separate variables but this equation can get more complicated and I want a general numerical solution for it. Also, the parameters of interest are a, b and E and as shown E is inside exp function `np.exp(-E / 3060.8)` , so there is no t in it and E is just a constant I want to find

Comment: it is not possible to separate three parameters a, b and E. You will only get two distinct constants: a.exp(-E/3060.8) and b.exp(-E/3060.8). Your method is fundamentally flawed.